# (Linguagem R) Como pedir um input no formato de data frame a um usuário?

Tags: r, data.frame

Estou fazendo uma função que percorre data frames em busca de valores não numéricos. Para tanto, tenho que pedir ao usuário que forneça como input um data frame. Assim, escrevo:

```
data.frame <- readline(prompt = "Insira Nome do DataFrame: ")
```

Porém, após inserir o nome do data frame, o que fica salvo em "data.frame" é uma string correspondente ao que foi digitado. Dei uma pesquisada e ví que a função readline() faz isso mesmo, mas não encontrei uma que fizesse o que eu queria, ou seja, receber e salvar adequadamente os dados no formato data frame. Alguém tem uma sugestão?
Talvez seja importante eu mencionar que os data frames que servem de input estão carregados no Enviroment do R.
Estou com o TidyVerse instalado e operante.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para obter um objeto do R a partir de uma string com o seu nome, use a função [`get`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/get.html).
Nota: mudei o nome da string para `dataframe`, sem o ponto, uma vez que `data.frame` já é o nome de uma função do R base.

```
dataframe <- readline(prompt = "Insira Nome do DataFrame: ")
#Insira Nome do DataFrame: iris

dataframe <- get(dataframe)
head(dataframe)
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```